# How can I stop my computer from waking up accidentally while keeping wake on lan features enabled?

Tags: windows-7, networking, sleep

My wireless network card is allowed to wake my computer, only by using a magic packet. This was done in device manager, for the purpose of using TeamViewer remotely.
However, the problem that I'm having is that after putting the computer into sleep mode, it will wake again approx. 5 minutes later. I did not send a signal to do so via teamviewer or any other software.

In command prompt, `powercfg -lastwake` reveals that it is the network card that is causing the wake.
Is there any way to find the reason why my network card is receiving a wake signal, even though I never sent one? Thank you.

Comment: I had a similar problem, turned out in my case that the network card was OracleVM virtual network adapter. If I had OracleVM running and put my pc to sleep, it would wake up after 5 minutes too. Maybe you have the same problem?

Comment: I've disabled the wake on lan features for all 3 network devices related to OracleVM and it still turns on. I don't keep OracleVM running. The 'powercfg -lastwake' still shows my actual wifi card as the culprit.

Comment: I didn't post this as an answer, but only something to check. In my case it was OracleVM that woke up the pc, and someone else who finds this question may have that problem. So it was worth mentioning it in a comment. If I was sure this was the answer, I would've posted an answer instead.